# How do I make a single progress chart (with five variables) in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, graph, progress-bar

I am trying to make a single progress chart in Google Sheets with five variables. I have provided a photo of an example I am attempting to replicate. Suggestions on how to build this would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmJ3h.jpg)

I have attempted to make a box and whisker chart, but that does not turn out the way I want it. I have also tried a stacked bar chart but I am unable to get the look that I want.

Comment: Just my 2c. I don't think that there is a native/built-in method to create the progress bar that you have in mind. Among other things, the width of each column/variable is sized according to its value among the five variables. I would manually edit the column widths and then use Conditional formatting to add the colours as the variables progress.